Exporting a Bert-based PyTorch model to CoreML. How can I make the CoreML model work for any input?
I use the code below to export a Bert-based PyTorch model to CoreML.
Since I used
dummy_input = tokenizer("A French fan", return_tensors="pt")

the CoreML model only works with that input when tested on macOS. How can I make the CoreML model work for any input (i.e., any text)?

Export script:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Core ML Export
pip install transformers torch coremltools nltk
"""
import os
from transformers import AutoModelForTokenClassification, AutoTokenizer
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import nltk
import coremltools as ct

nltk.download('punkt')

# Load the model and tokenizer
model_path = os.path.join('model')
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(model_path, local_files_only=True)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path, local_files_only=True)

# Modify the model's forward method to return a tuple
class ModifiedModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(ModifiedModel, self).__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.device = model.device  # Add the device attribute

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids=None):
        outputs = self.model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids)
        return outputs.logits


modified_model = ModifiedModel(model)

# Export to Core ML
def convert_to_coreml(model, tokenizer):
    # Define a dummy input for tracing
    dummy_input = tokenizer("A French fan", return_tensors="pt")
    dummy_input = {k: v.to(model.device) for k, v in dummy_input.items()}

    # Trace the model with the dummy input
    traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model, (
    dummy_input['input_ids'], dummy_input['attention_mask'], dummy_input.get('token_type_ids')))

    # Convert to Core ML
    inputs = [
        ct.TensorType(name="input_ids", shape=dummy_input['input_ids'].shape),
        ct.TensorType(name="attention_mask", shape=dummy_input['attention_mask'].shape)
    ]
    if 'token_type_ids' in dummy_input:
        inputs.append(ct.TensorType(name="token_type_ids", shape=dummy_input['token_type_ids'].shape))

    mlmodel = ct.convert(traced_model, inputs=inputs)

    # Save the Core ML model
    mlmodel.save("model.mlmodel")
    print("Model exported to Core ML successfully")

convert_to_coreml(modified_model, tokenizer)

To use the exported model:
import os
from transformers import AutoModelForTokenClassification, AutoTokenizer
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import nltk
import coremltools as ct
from coremltools.models import MLModel
import numpy as np
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import nltk

nltk.download('punkt')

# Load the Core ML model
model = MLModel('model.mlmodel')

# Load the tokenizer
model_path = 'model'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path, local_files_only=True)

def prepare_input(text, tokenizer):
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(text)
    tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(tokens, is_split_into_words=True, return_tensors="np")
    input_ids = tokenized_inputs['input_ids'].astype(np.int32)
    attention_mask = tokenized_inputs['attention_mask'].astype(np.int32)
    
    input_data = {
        'input_ids': input_ids,
        'attention_mask': attention_mask
    }
    
    if 'token_type_ids' in tokenized_inputs:
        input_data['token_type_ids'] = tokenized_inputs['token_type_ids'].astype(np.int32)
    
    return input_data, tokens

def predict(text):
    # Prepare the input
    input_data, tokens = prepare_input(text, tokenizer)
    
    # Make the prediction
    prediction = model.predict(input_data)
    
    # Extract the predicted labels
    logits = prediction['output']  # Adjust this key according to your model's output
    predicted_label = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)[0]
    
    # Display the results
    for word, label in zip(tokens, predicted_label):
        print(f"{word}: {model.model_description.outputDescriptions[0].dictionaryType.int64KeyType.stringDictionary[label]}")

# Test the model with a sentence
predict("A French fan")

The script only works with the example 'A French Fan'. When I tried another example predict("A footbal fan is standing in the stadium."), it triggers an error:
NSLocalizedDescription = "MultiArray shape (1 x 12) does not match the shape (1 x 5) specified in the model description";


Environments:

Export script: Tested Python 3.10 and torch 2.3.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 (does not work on Windows 10).
Prediction script: must be run on macOS 10.13+, as CoreML model only supports predictions on macOS 10.13+.


The problem is that you're converting the model using the shape of your dummy_input, which is 1 x 12, and the ct.convert() function assumes this will always be the shape of your input. If you want to be able to use any number of tokens up to the context length of your model, you need to modify the shape argument to look like this:
    inputs=[
        ct.TensorType(name="input_ids", shape=(1, ct.RangeDim(1, 512)), dtype=np.int32),
        ct.TensorType(name="attention_mask", shape=(1, ct.RangeDim(1, 512)), dtype=np.int32)
    ],

Where the 1 argument in ct.RangeDim() is the minimum context size and the 512 argument is your model's maximum context size.
You'll also want to add some arguments to the tokenizer() function to ensure it pads out the remainder of these tensors so it fits your model. You'll want to find the dimensions of your model's input size so you can give it the correct size.
dummy_input = tokenizer("This is a sample input", return_tensors="pt", padding='max_length', max_length=512)

You'll want to add the same arguments to your tokenizer() function when inferencing as well.
Apple's CoreML Documentation: https://apple.github.io/coremltools/docs-guides/source/flexible-inputs.html#set-the-range-for-each-dimension
ct.RangeDim() Documentation: https://apple.github.io/coremltools/source/coremltools.converters.mil.input_types.html#rangedim
